# Edit Excel table data in SharePoint using forms

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an Excel table with data but here the rows and columns each have meaning, for example:

```
          ColHead1   ColHead2  ColHead3
RowHead1  Data11      Data12   Data13
RowHead2  Data21      etc.     etc.
RowHead3
```

I would like users to edit the data using SharePoint forms.

I've considered the following options

1. Flatten the data and manually add editors for each field onto the form (so that I can simulate some sort of grid layout). This may become unmanageable if I need to make a change though.
2. Insert the data into a list and let SharePoint create a default form, but this will also flatten the data.

Is it possible to somehow use the data in SharePoint directly in a List (or lists) without flattening?

Or should I just post the Excel sheets for direct editing in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. 2-D data cannot be handled by SharePoint.

The best solution here would be to use Excel Services.

1. In 2007, Excel Services did not allow to write changes to backend file. I am not sure if the situation has changed with SharePoint 2010. You might have to check it out.
2. You can also put Excel file in document library itself.

However, what I am missing here are the business objectives for this requirement. What essentially do you want to achieve by putting this data in SharePoint forms ? May be there is some better way which others will be able to suggest if they know actual requirements.

Comment: I have data on separate sheets in the same workbook, but I need to set permission levels based on windows logon to prevent certain people from editing certain sheets. This can't be done in Excel (except through generic passwords). I also have a master sheet which aggregates some calculations from the other sheets, this can be done easily in sharpoint lists - using calcuations on the view.